# Black Triangle When Playing Videos

Tags: video, vlc

Whenever I play a video file it has a black triangle near the top left corner. It seems to be somewhat related to sound. It's not constant but seems to show up when the sound is really loud or the area it shows in is over-exposed. It happens for all videos of any format. might be a vlc problem but I'm stumped. It's not a perfect triangle, it has a blocky profile and changes in size and shape slightly when it pops in. The maximum size is the same all the time. Its size is relative to the window size.

Comment: thats the vlc cone icon